# Como redirecionar formulário a um código de verificação?

Tags: php, html, captcha

Quando o usuário clicar em “Cadastre-se”, o serviço pede que você digite as palavras de verificação de segurança. Se você não conseguir ler o que está escrito, pode clicar no link “Tente palavras diferentes”, ou pode ouvir as palavras, clicando em “um captcha sonoro”.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1):

### Captcha (por [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA))

> CAPTCHA é um acrônimo da expressão "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart" (teste de Turing público completamente automatizado para diferenciação entre computadores e humanos): um teste de desafio cognitivo, utilizado como ferramenta anti-spam, desenvolvido pioneiramente na universidade de Carnegie-Mellon. Como o teste é administrado por um computador, em contraste ao teste de Turing padrão que é administrado por um ser humano, este teste é na realidade corretamente descrito como um teste de Turing reverso.

### Um exemplo de captcha com reCAPTCHA

- [Link para requisição de chave para usar a API](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin?hl=pt-BR#createsite)

Exemplo de formulário HTML com o trecho:

```
<form method="post" action="verify.php">
    <?php
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $publickey = "your_public_key"; // cadastre-se no link informado acima
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Trecho para validar do lado do servidor:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key"; // observe a imagem em anexo.
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
      // seu fluxo caso o usuário tenha errado o captcha
  } else {
      // seu fluxo caso o usuário tenha acertado o captcha
  }
?>
```

Informações adicionais depois que se cadastrar para uso da API:

[image: Painel de controle reCAPTCHA]

[Fonte e documentação adicional](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=pt-BR)

### Uma curiosidade sobre o reCAPTCHA (offtopic, por [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA))

> O serviço reCAPTCHA fornece, para os sites inscritos, imagens de
>   palavras que o reconhecimento óptico de caractéres (OCR) software não
>   foi capaz de identificar. Estes sites inscritos (os quais seus
>   propósitos não são geralmente relacionados à ajuda do projeto de
>   digitalização de livros) apresentam estas imagens para humanos
>   decifrarem como palavras CAPTCHAs, como parte do seu procedimento
>   normal de validação. Depois eles retornam os resultados para o serviço
>   reCAPTCHA, que envia esses resultados para a digitalização de seus
>   projetos.